# Where is the quote "Informal proofs are algorithms, formal proofs are code" from?

Tags: reference-request, proofs, proof-assistants

Does anyone know the origin of the quote,

> Informal proofs are algorithms; formal proofs are code.

Its made [in Benjamin C. Pierce et al.'s Software Foundations](https://web.archive.org/web/20170512232112/https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/sf/current/Induction.html#lab48).

Answer (score 5):

He doesn't cite any references for it and 
Google doesn't return any results so 
I don't think he is really quoting from anywhere.

The idea that a proof is a "construction" 
(a term in intuitionistic/constructive mathematics 
with a very close meaning to what we call algorithm nowadays) 
goes back to at least [Luitzen Egbertus Jan Brouwer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L._E._J._Brouwer).
Note that Brouwer was talking about informal proofs 
as typically stated by mathematicians, 
not formalized proofs which are a very recent phenomenon.

The idea that a formal proof is a like a program in a programming language
can be traced back to at least to 
the [BHK interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer%E2%80%93Heyting%E2%80%93Kolmogorov_interpretation) of intuitionistic logic by [Arend Heyting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arend_Heyting).
The formal correspondence is [Curry-Howard isomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence).